# Média não é calculada

Tags: c, algoritmo, matemática

Preciso escrever um código que leia apenas 20 valores inteiros, no final some os números positivos e faça a média do números negativos.

Ele soma normalmente os positivos mas quando chega na hora dos negativos sempre mostra o valor 0.

Eis o meu código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
      int numerospositivos=0, soma=0, media, total=0, numero, 
      totalnegativo=0;

      float numerosnegativos=0;

      while(total<=20){
      printf("Digite um numero");
      scanf("%d",&numero);

    if(numero<0){
    numerosnegativos+=numero;
      totalnegativo++;}

      else if(numero>=0){
    numerospositivos+=numero;
    total++;}
    }

    media=numerosnegativos/totalnegativo;
    soma=numerospositivos;

      printf("A media dos numeros negativos e de:  %f",media);
      printf("A soma dos numeros positivos e:   %d",soma);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um dos motivos do problema é que você não preza muito por organizar o código e isto pode parecer bobagem, mas faz diferença até cognitiva no que está aprendendo e fazendo. Veja que escrevendo melhor fica mais fácil entender porque o erro ocorre.

Pense no problema da forma mais simples possível.

Se quer ler uma quantidade específica de itens o `for` sempre é mais recomendado e simples. Vira até algo padrão para se usar.

Se quer somar algo, basta ir acumulando como fez. Mas tem um erro, está incrementando o número o número de lidos condicionalmente, ou seja, só quando lê 20 positivos que o laço encerra. Se tivesse usado um `for` provavelmente evitaria esse problema. E note que está usando um `else if` onde um `else` já basta, um é condição exatamente contrária ao outro.

Só no caso de negativos precisa acumular e contar quanto são porque para calcular a média precisa do total e de quantos são para fazer a divisão.

Outra coisa que eu sempre digo que se declarar a variável mais próxima de onde será usada fica mais fácil lidar com ela e saber porque ela existe.

Eu transformei o total em `float` para dar um número quebrado, mas isso não é requisito colocado no enunciado, então sem ele deveria funcionar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int somaPositivos = 0, somaNegativos = 0, negativos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("\nDigite um numero");
        int numero;
        scanf("%d", &numero);
        if (numero < 0) {
            somaNegativos += numero;
            negativos++;
        } else somaPositivos += numero;
    }
    printf("A media dos numeros negativos é de:  %f\n", (float)somaNegativos / negativos);
    printf("A soma dos numeros positivos é: %d\n", somaPositivos);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ceUvC3). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ldqbpjqr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Media.c).